# mq_receive returns "Message too long" even though msg_len is greater than mq_msgsize

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, posix, message-queue

I am trying to understand the working of message queues in Linux.

Eventually, I'd want to have a program where I could send and receive stuff between different threads/processes, but to start off, I only create a message queue, and have it block on an input in a queue, but `mq_receive()` returns `Message too long`.

Looking at the documentation, this error indicates `msg_len was less than the mq_msgsize attribute of the message queue., but this isn't the case for me.

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious but I couldn't figure it out.

```
#define MAX_MESSAGES 10
#define MAX_MSG_SIZE 256
#define MSG_BUFFER_SIZE MAX_MSG_SIZE + 10


int main() 
{
     mqd_t qd_server, qd_client;
     char in_buffer [MSG_BUFFER_SIZE];
     char out_buffer [MSG_BUFFER_SIZE];
 
    struct mq_attr attr, tmpAttr;  
    attr.mq_flags = 0;
    attr.mq_maxmsg = MAX_MESSAGES;
    attr.mq_msgsize = MAX_MSG_SIZE;
    attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;
    
    
    if ((qd_server = mq_open ("/sp-example-server", O_RDONLY|O_CREAT, 0644, &attr)) == -1) 
    {
         printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
    }


    if (mq_getattr(qd_server, &tmpAttr) == -1)
    {
               printf("mq_getattr error");
    }

        printf("Maximum # of messages on queue:   %ld\n", tmpAttr.mq_maxmsg);
        printf("Maximum message size:             %ld\n", tmpAttr.mq_msgsize);


    int iret = mq_receive(qd_server, in_buffer, sizeof(in_buffer), NULL);
    if (iret == -1)
    {   
         printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

After running `mmq_getattr(qd_server, & tmpAttr)`, it seems as if attributes were never set which probably is the cause. Now on to why are attributes not set?

```
// output:

Maximum # of messages on queue:   10
Maximum message size:             8192
```

Comment: Are you sure the `mq_msgsize` is what you think it is?  You're not opening the queue O_EXCLusively.  What does `mq_gettattr` say?

Comment: you're right, the values weren't set but why would that be? Without `O_EXCL`, it won't create a file at all so `qd_server` is not populated?

Comment: after looking it up, it looks like `O_EXCL` basically aborts the function when used with `O_CREAT` if message queue already exists, but in my case, it's the only queue created and there isn't any prior

Comment: What do you mean the "attributes were never set"?  Please show us the code, show us their values, and describe how you know their values are wrong.

Comment: you can see the attributes aren't set to values that were set in the program

Answer (score 0):

The code you've shown us did not create the `/sp-example-server` message queue.

Instead, some prior process created that queue with the values you see for `mq_maxmsg` and `mq_msgsize`.  If the queue's creator omitted the attribute specification — that is, passed a NULL `struct mq_attr *` to `mq_open` — then [the implementation will provide default values](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mq_open.html#tag_16_338_03).  On Linux, [these defaults match the values you see](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html#DESCRIPTION).

It seems plausible some early version of your code called `mq_open` with NULL attributes, and thus O_CREAT'd the queue as you are experiencing it now.

To accommodate this, you might reboot or `mq_unlink` the queue, forcing the next call to `mq_open` to re-create it.  More defensively, when you do *not* open the queue O_EXCLusively, then use `mq_getattr` to validate the queue's attributes.

Comment: if the `/sp-example-server` wasn't created, shouldn't the `open()` have failed? how do you verify if the queue was even created else? also is there a way to see what existing queues are already allocated?